# Julia handling void return type

Tags: julia

What is the best method for handling a `Void` type when it is returned by a function? The suggestions in http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/faq/#how-does-null-or-nothingness-work-in-julia don't work.

A MWE (must be run from the REPL so `Base.source_dir()` returns `Void`):

```
julia> isempty(Base.source_dir())
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching start(::Void)
Closest candidates are:
  start(::SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:170
  start(::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:258
  start(::IntSet) at intset.jl:184
  ...
 in isempty(::Void) at ./iterator.jl:3
 in isempty(::Void) at /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib:?

julia> isdefined(Base.source_dir())
ERROR: TypeError: isdefined: expected Symbol, got Void

julia> typeof(Base.source_dir()) == Void
true
```

This is on Julia 0.5. The latter option works, but it's a bit ugly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Void` is a singleton -- a type with exactly one instance.
That one instance is `Void()` also called `nothing`.
Be aware that `nothing === Void()`

You can treat it just like any other value.

It is returned by a bunch of functions, like `println`.

You can check if something has returned `nothing` -- ie and instance of type `Void`.

By

```
julia> println()===nothing
true
```

For the sake of type-stability,
a method should not return `nothing` some of the time, and something some of the time.
in those case it should instead return a `Nullable`,
generally.

Comment: `===` is generally recommended, as it is possible to extend `==` in weird ways.